# Scheme DrRacket Not Defined Error

Tags: ide, scheme, racket

Hello I am learning Scheme.Sometimes I face a problem that I could not understand.Here it is. I am using DrRacket.In a tab I am defining a function then I run it.For using it I write (functionName parameter) to terminal part.But it says "functionName is not defined." Then I open a new tab.Copy the function there and run it.Then write the same to terminal and it works fine.Why is that happening? Any of you faced this problem? Thank you from now ...

Comment: That sounds very odd. If you just add "hello" to the bottom of the definitions window and run it, does the interaction window print "hello"?

Comment: no.maybe I am choosing wrong language from bottom.There are pretty big, etc.What should I choose?

Comment: Pick "The Racket Language" and use "#lang racket" as the first line of your Definitions.

Comment: there is always error.Are there any options please ?

Comment: @ayshee Show us your code. We can help you make it work with "The Racket Language".

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young                                                                            (define (square x)
      (* x x)) 
    (define (>= x y)
      (or (> x y) (= x y)))
    (define (karekok x)
      (the y (and (>= y 0) (= (square y) x))))

Comment: when I write (karekok 36) it says karekok: this function is not defined

Comment: What is `the` (in `(the y ...)`)? It's not defined in default Racket. Is it from a library you're using?

Comment: In my book it says like that in procedures subject.That is why I used that.

Comment: @ayshee What's the book? `the` is most likely defined in there somewhere. (I believe it's a procedure such that `(the y condition)` means "a `y` that satisfies `condition`".)

Answer (score 0):

Strong suggestion to you: put *everything* in the definitions window. Fundamentally, this is why the definitions window was created. When you put everything in the definitions window, then the behavior of a program can be completely constrained. So, for instance, if you run this program:

```
#lang racket

(define (square x) (* x x))

(define (>= x y) (or (> x y) (= x y)))

(define (karekok x) (the y (and (>= y 0) (= (square y) x))))
```

In the "The Racket Language" language level, I'm extremely confident that you'll get the same result that I do.

Specifically, an error that reads:

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 6.4.0.4--2016-01-19(-/f) [3m].
Language: racket [custom]; memory limit: 128 MB.
. the: unbound identifier in module in: the
>
```

If you edit your question to provide your complete program, I bet that we'll be able to help.